# How to integrate a wordpress site on my magento marketplace with the same access credentials for both portals

Tags: wordpress, magento, magento-1.9

I run an e-commerce website built using Magento, I want to create a jobs listing portal using wordpress. There are  a few ready plug-ins that I can use. The audience of my e-commerce website could be both a job-seeker and job-lister. I want them to have a single login so that they are not asked for credentials twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were are two Magento plugins that I'm aware of that do what you want.

The free one doesn't seem to be supported anymore.  :(  But the one is actively supported and does exactly what you want.  http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/customer-synchronisation/  It's not too spendy, and it's designed for your use case.

You can also try to tackle this from the Wordpress side using a plugin like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/ but it will take some coding on your side to make it do what you want.

Comment: Thank you! The FishPig plug-in looks really useful.

Comment: Don't forget to mark question as answered and upvote.  :)